# WSO2 API Manager 1.8 behind HAProxy Issue

Tags: ssl, wso2, haproxy, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to run twp WSO2 API Manager 1.8 behind a HAProxy for HA purpose. Below are the configuration that's done up to now. Below configuration is the only newly added one, others are as it's.

```
listen am_cluster 0.0.0.0:443
        mode tcp
        balance roundrobin
        #option httpclose
        #option forwardfor
        #cookie JSESSIONID prefix indirect nocache
        #cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
        server am1 192.168.X.ABC:9443  check
        server am2 192.168.X.ABD:9443  check
```

This require 2 SSL certifications from user when he try to access the API store.

- How can I fix this ?
- Else What's the best way to load balance a WSO2 API Manager cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+HAProxy) which contains instructions on how to configure HAProxy for WSO2 Products. Also It has instructions on creating the SSL certificates.

FYI, [WSO2 Product Clustering documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Overview) has lot of information on different ways of clustering and load balancing WSO2 Products.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but it still require two certification when accessing the API Manager. Backend certification is checked. How can I fix this?